# DNN file manager is showing 'no permission' error when uploading files

Tags: permissions, file-manager, dnn9

I have created a new DotNetNuke user and gave him a new User Role.

I have linked this role to his username and gave the role permissions to upload to a certain folder on the server in the File Manager module.

For some reason, it is giving a 'No Permission' error when he/she tries to upload a file. The DNN version is 9.1.0

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I recomend you to upgrade DNN to last stable version (9.3.2). And check that the folder (and subfolders) containing DNN have the required permissions.
Now, it's the moment to check inside DNN: sometimes folders lose their permissions; go to file manager, click on root folder and make sure it has the proper permissions, then propagate them to subfolders.
Let us know if you get tid of errors.